parsing binary data in kotlin similar to python struct_unpack
How to parse binary data in kotlin when receiving it from server?
My kotlin client is receiving a stream of binary data from server. I can parse it with python with the below code:
from struct import unpack_from
import socket


HOST = "127.0.0.1" 
PORT = 12345

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        data = s.recv(7000)

        header_size = 4  # 4 bytes header
        print(f"type: {type(data)}, size: {len(data)}, data: {data[0:10]}")
        print("msgSize", unpack_from("!I", data, 0))
        print("msgType", unpack_from("!B", data, offset=header_size))  # size + msgType

        group_one = unpack_from("!I", the_msg, offset=4)
        group_two = unpack_from("!I", the_msg, offset=8)
        header_blob_length = unpack_from("!I", the_msg, offset=12)
        header_blob = unpack_from(f"!{header_blob_length[0]}s", the_msg, offset=16)



>>> type: <class 'bytes'>, size: 6985, data: b'\x00\x00\x1bE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00'
>>> msgSize (6981,)
>>> msgType (0,)

And this will properly give me the results I am looking for.
But I am having trouble trying to replicate this in Kotlin. What I've tried so far:

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val host: String = "localhost"
    val port: Int = 12345

    runBlocking {
        val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
        val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect(host, port)

        val receiveChannel = socket.openReadChannel()

        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(7000).order(BIG_ENDIAN) 
            while (true) {
                buffer.clear()
                val bytesRead = receiveChannel.readAvailable(buffer)
                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    val binaryData = ByteArray(bytesRead)
                    buffer.flip()
                    val a = buffer.slice()

                    println(binaryData.joinToString(separator = " ", prefix = "[", postfix = "]"))
                }
                println(bytesRead)
            }
        }

    }
}

But this seems to be giving me the data wrongly. Because in the python code, I can struct_unpack it based on the different byte size (sometimes 4, sometimes more). I can't seem to reproduce the same with Kotlin code. Any tips is appreciated!

Does my answer here answer your question?
